# How do I work out which port to log in on with SSH?

Tags: ssh, tcp

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 server setup remotely that I setup a while back. While I recorded the username and password, I seem to have been clever and changed the usual ssh port from 22 to... something else.

How do I find out what that port might be?

I do have access to the server via the hosting company's back door, so I can execute whatever Unix commands are needed - but I cannot log in using a normal putty shell on my machine.

Comment: This is probably silly, and you have good answers already, but if you have connected in the past, you could check your terminal history and/or `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 40):

First check on the config file which port is configured:

```
$ sudo grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 22
```

Then either restart `ssh` to make sure it loads the config you just saw or find out on which port `ssh` is running:

```
$ sudo netstat -tpln | egrep '(Proto|ssh)'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12586/sshd
```

That's a normal `ssh` running on port 22.

Comment: Just a note: I don't think you need sudo

Comment: In the first command you need `sudo` because usually the `sshd` config file is not world readable. In the second you need `sudo` to be able to resolve the `Program name`, otherwise you can only see the name for the processes runing under your own user.

Comment: I agree with @piertoni, you don't need to run this command with "SUDO".

Comment: I add a note: it's discouraged to modify main file. Probably new configs and overrides are added into subfolder/sshd_config.d. So check these file also

Answer (score 11):

If you have access to the server through other means, just run:

```
$ sudo grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Port NNN
```

That will return a line like the one shown above where `NNN` will be the port you chose.

Answer (score 6):

The easier way is just looking at the SSH server configuration files:

```
➜  ~  sudo grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
   Port 22
```

There's also checking for listening ports per process with `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof -Pi | grep ssh
```

or any other ports listing command like `netstat -lntu`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have login access to the server, you can find the SSH port using `nmap`'s "version scan" feature:

```
nmap -sV -p- <insert target's IP here>
```

The `-sV` option means "version scan", and `-p-` means "scan all ports".  If you've got a good connection and are sure you won't be upsetting someone's firewall or IDS, you can add `-T5` for "scan as fast as possible".  The results will look something like this:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
1422/tcp open  ssh      (protocol 2.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the server's console, you'll have to probe all the ports from a distant host. These utilities are like `nmap`, however the network layer must relay traffic to the specific combination of host (IP address) AND port.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo netstat -lntp
[sudo] password for XXX:
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address  State        PID/Program name
tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:22       0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN       2799/sshd
tcp6  0      0      :::22            :::*             LISTEN       2799/sshd
```